# How to query all parent with no child, and last existing child of a parent when only 2 levels?

Tags: sql, sql-server

English is not my first language, so I will try to explain what I'm looking for as clearly as possible. I tried many hours of searching but I can't find exactly what I need.

I have the following table structure, which is a simple parent/child hierarchy. I will ever have only 2 levels (ex.: records with no child, records with children and those children won't have child):

table structure:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ParentId] [int] NULL,
```

[image]

Here is the data in the table:

```
Id          Description       ParentId
----------- ----------------- -----------
1           aaaa              NULL
2           bbbb              NULL
3           cccc              NULL
4           dddd              NULL
5           eeee              NULL
6           ffff              NULL
7           gggg              NULL
8           aaaa-2            1
9           aaaa-3            1
10          bbbb-2            2
11          bbbb-3            2
```

Data in the table:

[image]

I want the query to return all the records with no child, and the last occurrence of a parent's child without returning the corresponding parent.  See the next image for the expected result (I want the query to return only the records marked in color):

Expected results:

```
Id          Description       ParentId
----------- ----------------- -----------
3           cccc              NULL
4           dddd              NULL
5           eeee              NULL
6           ffff              NULL
7           gggg              NULL
9           aaaa-3            1
11          bbbb-3            2
```

[image]

I tried something like:

```
WITH CTE ([Id], [Description], [ParentId], LEVEL) AS
( SELECT [Id], [Description], [ParentId], 1 LEVEL
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Avis]`enter code here`
  WHERE [ParentId] IS NULL AND [Id] NOT IN ??
  UNION ALL
  SELECT E.[Id], E.[Description], E.[ParentId], CTE.LEVEL + 1
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Avis] E
      INNER JOIN CTE CTE ON E.[ParentId] = CTE.[Id]
  WHERE E.[ParentId] IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Sorry for the included images, i was not able to include them directly since I don't have enough point on stack overflow.

Comment: Formatted text has no reputation requirement!

Comment: Thanks jarlh for the editing, took me some time to get what happened while I was trying to prepare a full text version and came back here.

Comment: Why not post images of tables and code? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two requirements:

1. Get all rows not in a relationship
2. Get the last child of each parent

Essentially you're trying to get the last leaf in every relationship.

To get all rows not in a relationship, get those rows who have a null parent id and whose id is not used as a parent id on another row.

To get the last children, use a sub query get the max id for each parent id and use those ids to select the rows you need.

You could split those two requirements into two queries with a union, but since the not a parent requirement won't hurt the leaves, you can just split the null parent id or has max id requirement with an or.

```
SELECT *
FROM @Avis a
WHERE a.Id NOT IN (SELECT ParentId FROM @Avis WHERE ParentId IS NOT NULL)
    AND (
        a.ParentId IS NULL 
        OR a.Id IN (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @Avis WHERE ParentId IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ParentId)
    )
```

**Results**

```
Id          Description  ParentId
----------- ------------ -----------
3           cccc         NULL
4           dddd         NULL
5           eeee         NULL
6           ffff         NULL
7           gggg         NULL
9           aaaa-3       1
11          bbbb-3       2
```

Bonus: this query will get the last leaf for each parent even if the relationships are multiple levels deep.